# Function has Invalid Arguements

Tags: c#

I feel like this should be a simple concept; however, I seem to be missing something.
I am receiving the error "the best overloaded ,method match for 'test.rawr(String[])' has some invalid arguments"

Any ideas? I have a feeling I'm missing something very fundamental...

I have a function that I am passing a URL to, handling that URL, and doing normal "stuff" 
Code below:

```
    public int very_very_sad()
{

    rawr("My-Url_here");
}
public static void rawr(string[] args)
{
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function accepts only string[], but you are passing a string,

Change your function as below,

```
public int very_very_sad()
{    
    rawr("My-Url_here");
}
public static void rawr(string args)
{
}
```

Comment: . . . Well, I've made a fool of myself, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `string[]` as the method is expecting `string[]` and not just a `string`.

Do this:

```
 rawr(new string[]{"My-Url_here"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `string` to a function accepting a `string[]` (string array). You probably wanted a variable length parameter list:

```
public static void rawr(params string[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what I see is that you should pass an array instead of a string variable only